# Julian Date to Datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, julian-date

I have the following columns in a table

```
Year    Julian_Day  Time_HHMM   Seconds Decimal_Day
2015    271             2000       0        0.7415013
```

The ouput datetime is `"2015-09-28 20:00:00"`

I tried to figure out how to convert those parameters to datetime but I havent had luck.
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by nesting calls to the [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function for the various components:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, [Seconds], DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(RIGHT([Time_HHMM], 2) AS INT), DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(LEFT([Time_HHMM], 2) AS INT), DATEADD(DAY, [Julian_Day] - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, [Year] - 1900, 0)))))
FROM   YourTable
```

Note I have not used the `Decimal_Day` column.

`DATEADD` takes integer parameters for the components, so you may need some additional casting on the columns to INT, if they are currently of type VARCHAR.

Comment: Note it is not a Julian day you're using - Julian days are the number of whole days since noon on January 1, 4713 BC. Basically I've taken this to mean your `Julian_Day` column is actually days since the start of the year, at midnight (from your expected output this is the only thing that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/47d773c3-dae2-41cc-8770-5f2f24a1c665/julian-date-to-datetime-conversion][1]

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @JulianDate / 1000 - 1900, @JulianDate % 1000 - 1)
```